# What are the differences between Carmageddon and the free promotional version?

Tags: android, version-differences, carmageddon

When [Carmageddon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stainlessgames.carmageddon) was released on android, there was a 'free' promotional version released at the same time for one day only - I am not talking about ['Carma Free'](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stainlessgames.carmageddonfree) which is obviously a demo of some kind, but the free-for-a-day promotional version.

I got the promotional version on release day and have completed it and I am wondering if there are any differences between the free-for-a-day version and the currently not-free version? Are these both the same full version of the game?

Comment: Do you remember the package name of this promotional version? I had it in my history and now it's gone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are the same game.

Unfortunately, Google doesn't allow free apps to turn into paid apps in the Play Store, so after the 24 hours were up, the promo version got pulled from the store and therefore **won’t receive any updates**. You can still opt for the paid version or use the demo version afterwards if you want to see the updates to the app.

So basically the app you have is the same game but the initial version of it.

Comment: +1 for interesting info. Did not know the Play store did this.